# Determine an empty array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am developing an admin backend for an android app for a restaurant. I need to list all food items the restaurant offers based on their categories. The trouble is there can be some categories which doesn't have any item listed under it, and if such a category is encountered the php back end is supposed to return just an empty list but the category name should be there.

My current code so far

```
try
    {
        $query = "SELECT category FROM category";       
        $result= $DBH->query($query);
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $cat    = $row['category'];
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE catagory='$cat'";       
            $value  = $DBH->query($query1);
            $row1   = $value->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $main   = array('data'=>array($row1));
            echo json_encode($main);
        }

        $result->closeCursor();         //Close database connection free resources
        $DBH = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        print $e->getMessage ();
        die();
    }
```

Gives an output like this

```
{"data":[{"id":"2","name":"Rice","price":"120","description":"Plain Rice","image":"6990_abstract-photo-2.jpg","time":"12 mins","catagory":"Lunch","subcat":""}]}
{"data":[{"id":"4","name":"Dal","price":"5","description":"dadadad","image":"","time":"20 mins","catagory":"Dinner","subcat":""}]}
{"data":[false]}
```

My problem is the last output where it shows `{"data":[false]}` should be like this `{"data":["catagory":"Soup"]}` To do that I would need to find out when the `$main` variable is empty and then manually add the category to it.

Any ideas or work around to this situation?

Comment: Can't you just check if $main is empty and then added that default value before calling json_eoncode()? Really seems straightforward to me. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I tried using if(empty($main)) it always returns false even though the 3rd time it is empty

Comment: You should do var_dump() of $main and see what it looks like. It's obviously not what you think.

Comment: var_dump() shows that the 3rd time the value is array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) } } Can you suggest how I can use this to code a logic to attend my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want this modification..........

```
if ($row1   = $value->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  $main   = array('data'=>array($row1));
  echo json_encode($main);
}else{
  echo '{"data":["catagory":"' . $row['category'] . '"]}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem stems from the fact that you have a 'soup' category but you don't have any items belonging to the soup category. You should add a condition for empty result and change the echoing array accordingly.

```
  if (empty($row1))
  {
   $main   = array('data'=>array('category'=>$cat));
  }
   else 
  {
    $main   = array('data'=>array($row1));
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to actually do that but I am stumped as I can't detect when it is being empty. If you could give an example of condition to find out the empty result it would be great